# No Such File or Directory

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am trying to send an image file to server with help of retrofit2 library. But there is a problem. By the way I write my codes in MVP pattern.

I tried to send image files to server in different ways. One of them was AndroidNetworking for fast responses. But at last none of them worked. Problem is "File is not found".
I pick image from gallery of the phone and then I send that image to cropping processes with help of Android Image Cropper library. Here is my code which causes the exception:

```
    File file = new File(images.get(cursor).toString());

    //pass it like this
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

    mInteractor.onImageUploadRequest(
            body,
            SharedPreferencesManager.getStringData(mView.getContext(), Constants.TOKEN_KEY),
            new ImageCallback()
    );
```

The problem is:

> E/SharePostPresenter:
>   file:/data/user/0/org.kitapp/cache/cropped4247134528851651259.jpg (No
>   such file or directory)

Comment: Seems that problem is obvious: path of image that you provide is not correct. If you are using Image Cropper then you should have `Uri` of cropped image so did you try something like this: `File file = new File(uri.getPath());`

Comment: I have used new File(uri.toString());

Comment: Correct is to use `getPath()` instead of `toString()`

Comment: Yeap, it has worked. Thanks a lot )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that problem is obvious:

> path of image is not correct.

But if you are using Image Cropper library then you should have `Uri` of cropped image so try something like this: `File file = new File(uri.getPath());`

Note that `getPath()` is correct way to access the path from `Uri` instead of using `toString()`